# In Django 1.7, Python3, using Floppyforms 1.3, keep getting error "TypeError: object() takes no parameters"

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

This is now mostly informational now as I figured out the error.

Background: Django 1.7 app with an update form for MyModel.

My form looked like this:

```
import floppyforms as forms
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import *
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import *

class MyCustomForm(forms.ModelForm):
    user_name = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.CharField()
    phone = forms.CharField()
    first_name = forms.CharField()
    last_name = forms.CharField()

class Meta:
    model = MyCustomModel
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting the following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 64, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  ...
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/floppyforms/models.py", line 22, in __new__
    return super(ModelForm, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters`

I'm not sure why this keeps happening, but the error message doesn't help much.

Comment: You should split your question between a question and an answer. Adding some code will be nice. And you could keep only the "first" lines of the error message.

Answer (score 8):

Drove me nuts for a few days, finally resolved this by adding the `.__future__` to floppyforms import.

```
import floppyforms.__future__ as forms
```

Now code is happy :)